Use of "would" in a sentence
Can you explain how "would" works in B's sentence when replying to A's question? Can we substitute "would" for "will" in this context?

A: Should I use "the blossom of" or "the blossoming of"? Is "blossom" also the noun form of the verb "blossom"?


The blossoming of this plant always tells the coming of spring.


B: Idiomatic would be "blooming"

